# Maier's theorem

Tags: prime-numbers

I have some questions with [Maier's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maier%27s_theorem)

1. If $1 < \lambda < 2$, then what?
2. If $x+(\log x)^\lambda = x^{1+1/\pi(x)}$, then what?
3. In particular, if $\lambda = 0.525\log x/(\log\log x)$, then what?
   (see 
   [A result, due to Baker, Harman and Pintz in 2001, shows that θ may be taken to be 0.525.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) )

Comment: Re 1: If $1 < \lambda < 2$, the theorem applies.

Comment: Well, what does that mean? I look at the numerator as being a interval just like if the RHS of 2. was the numerator. So, I do not get the statement of how the theorem is applied or what it means.